# How arbitrary is one?

Tags: numbers, semantics, specifications

My teacher says our homework program must handle "an arbitrary number of input lines". It seems pretty arbitrary to only accept one line, but is it arbitrary *enough*? My roommate said seven is more a arbitrary number than one, and maybe he's right. But I just have no idea how to measure the arbitrariness of a number and [Google doesn't seem to help](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20measure%20the%20arbitrariness%20of%20a%20number&oq=how%20to%20measure%20the%20arbitrariness%20of%20a%20number&aqs=chrome..69i57.5456j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

UPDATE:

It sounds like maybe the best thing to do is accepty *any given* number of input lines, and hope the prof can see that that makes a lot more sense than insisting that the user just give you one specific *arbitrary* number of input lines. Especially since we weren't instructed to notify the user about what the arbitrary number is. You can't just make the user guess, that's crazy.

Comment: relevant: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Arbitrary" doesn't mean you get to pick a random number to accept. It means that it should handle an input with any number of lines.

So if someone decides to give your program an input with 0 lines, 1 line, 2 lines... n lines, then it should still do the right thing (and not crash).

Comment: But if it arbitrarily accepts one line, wouldn't the "Right Thing" be to issue an error message if there's 0 or > 1? It's not clear to me what the Right Thing IS, if it's required to be arbitrary.

Comment: "Arbitrary" means randomness on THE USER's part, not on YOUR part. We don't want your PROGRAM to be arbitrary, we want your program to handle a USER who gives arbitrary input.

Comment: But it's a requirement for the *program*, not the user. You can't spec out your user, you just get what you get.

Comment: From experience, I highly doubt your instructor meant "I want you to pick a random number, then write a program to handle that number of lines". More likely, they meant "I want you to write a program, such that no matter what random number I (the instructor) pick, your program can handle that many lines".

Comment: Or do you mean I should change the number every time it runs? But that's random, not arbitrary. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well if the only way to learn what instructors want is to take the class and guess the first time and see what grade you get, that hardly seems fair.

Comment: Well, I guess I'd better take your word for it and hope for the best. It does seem like realistically, you want to accept *any given* number (within reason) of input lines, not just one arbitrarily chosen number.

Comment: I am very close to 100% confident that this is what your instructor is asking.

Comment: Very close will have to do. That's funny, I was just talking with somebody about the difference between .999 repeating and 1.0...

Comment: @HerculesBagadonuts "accept any given number (within reason) of input lines" is the [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arbitrary) of arbitrary (see #3 in the link)

Comment: @CDspace "The equation is true for *an* arbitrary value of x." Right; in math, you have to figure out what that value of x is.

Comment: @HerculesBagadonuts Actually, no. The equation is true for "_any and all_" values of x, thus your program needs to handle any and all possible numbers of lines

Comment: @CDspace But then I would would have to write an infinite number of programs.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary means it could be ANY number. 0, 1, 7, 100124453225.

I would probably test for 0 and display some sort of error in that case since it's supposed to have SOME text. Other than that so long as there are more lines your program should keep doing whatever it's designed to do.

Comment: Do you mean 0 lines, or a line consisting of the text "0"?

Comment: 0 lines. A line that contained the text "0" would be one line. I typically would try to get the first line and if it's EOF you can throw an error message. If not you can do a while loop until you see EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when teachers indicate that a program should accept arbitrary amounts of input they are indicating to you that you should consider corner cases which you may not have thought about, one of the most common being no input at all which can often cause errors in programs if the programmer hasn't considered this case.

The point of the word is to emphasize that your program should be able to handle different inputs instead of simply crashing unless input comes in a certain quantity or is formatted in a specific way.

Comment: Well yeah no input is definitely an error condition. If the user doesn't have anything to say he shouldn't have run the program at all, not run it and then just change his mind and do nothing.